# SeekBar not showing up on view xml file

Tags: android

I am trying to get the SeekBar to display at the bottom of the screen but actually under the LinerLayout I created, but I can't seem to get it to display. I have split the screen into 5 sections and want the seek bar at the bottom of the screen, where am I going wrong?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/gray"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/green"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@color/green" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/blue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@color/blue" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/red"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@color/red" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/yellow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:background="@color/yellow" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your SeekBar layout_width to "match_parent":

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Slee it seems like it is not working, I can't see the seek bar and the bottom when I go in Graphical Layout.

Comment: @Dino I just updated my answer. In graphical layout, SeekBar is shown when its layout_width is set to match_parent. I think 0dp should work fine on the real device though. As xorgate suggested, you also need to change its orientation from horizontal to vertical.

Comment: I changed it to match_parent and I added in android:layout_weight="1.0" in the second LinearLayout (the root being the first LinearLayout in the document) and it showed up. I did change it from horizontal to vertical and all the squares were placed one below each other instead of the way I have it.

Comment: @Dino hmm why do you need the second one though? I think it should show up without the second LinearLayout which is duplication of the root one

Comment: It is the only way I seem to be able to place 5 boxes in the following order, 2 boxes on the left side and 3 on the right, with seek bar at the bottom. I used your code and added the line `android:layout_weight="1.0"`. However I am not sure if it will work if I remove the second LinearLayout.

Comment: @Dino Please accept the answer if it works on the real device or emulator.

Answer (score 0):

The encompassing linearlayout has orientation="horizontal", try setting it to "vertical".